# How can i use REGEX to parse commas as well as newline

Tags: java, regex, csv, parsing

I have this csv file which is formatted in such a way where there is a new line after a certain value. It looks like this:

`Value1, Value2, Value3, Value4`(/n)
`"Value5", "Value 6", "Value 7"`

As you can see, there is no comma deliminator between `value4` and `value5`. I have tried testing whether `array.split(\n)` will create a string array that deliminates the new line, however it ends up looking like:

`Value1, Value2, Value3, Value4"Value5", "Value6", "Value7"`.

I have this case block which determines the type of deliminator and executes a split for that character:

```
String[] recordValues;

        switch (fileType) {
            case "COMMA_DELIMITED":
                recordValues = record.split(",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");
```

I would like the end result to look from:
`Value1, Value2, Value3, Value4"Value5", "Value6", "Value7"`

To this: `Value1, Value2, Value3, Value4, "Value5", "Value6", "Value7"`

I apologize if this seems like a rather easy question, i am a bit stumped.

Comment: Are commas possible inside your values? For example, can `"Value5"` have a value like `"value1,2"`

Comment: @ctwheels there should not be any commas inside any of the values. They are being separated by the commas

Comment: My point is that if you split on `,`, it'll also split within values unless you design the regex properly (or even better, use a parser)

Comment: `s = s.replaceAll("\n\"", ", \"")`

Answer (score 0):

Splitting in Java is done by specifying regular expression so you have freedom to split by one or another character.

Your regex may look as follows:

```
array.split("\n|,");
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean '\n' (Your example is /n), this one will work for you:

```
String test = "Value1, Value2, Value3, Value4\n \"Value5\", \"Value 6\", \"Value 7\"";
String[] values = test.split(",|\n");
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.deepToString(values));
```